# Trying to run sonar-runner from shell script

Tags: sonar-runner, sonarqube

I want to run sonar runner every night via a cronjob though nothing happens when I run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

cd path_to_repo

git checkout master
echo "on master"
git pull
echo "pulled"

touch text.txt

sonar-runner
echo "finished scan"
```

When I run the command sonar-runner in the same folder it works fine.

Also I added a test command touch which also works. Only sonar-runner does not work.

Comment: have you added sonar-runner as a environment variable?

Comment: It does work when I run it in the command line, then the environment variable is added right?

Comment: Any message is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

So stupid. In the script I set the path, though I set it without the path to sonarqube...

The script works like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/var/www/sonarcube/sonarrunner/bin

cd path_to_file

git checkout master
echo "on master"
git pull
echo "pulled"

cd ../..
echo "back to root folder"

sonar-runner
echo "finished scan"
```